# why when i inherit from a generic interface in a generic abstract class casting does not work and i have to at first cast it to a the interface?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the below generic interface

```
public interface ITargetManager: ITargetManager<ITargetManager, ITarget>
    {

    }
public interface ITargetManager<TSelf, TI> : ITargetOptions
   where TSelf : ITargetManager<TSelf,TI>
   where TI : ITarget
{
    TI Build();
    void Update(TI target);
    TSelf WithProp1(int value);
    TSelf WithProp2(string value);
    TSelf WithProp3(int? value);
    TSelf WithProp4(string value);
}
```

and this abstract class implement it:

```
public abstract class TargetManager<TSelf, TI, T> :
        ITargetManager<TSelf, TI>
        where TSelf : ITargetManager<TSelf, TI>
        where TI : class, ITarget
        where T : TI
    {
        private int prop1;
        private string prop2;
        private int? prop3;
        private string prop4;
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> dic = new();
        public TargetManager(TI? target = null)
        {
            if (target == null) return;

            WithProp1(target.Prop1);
            WithProp2(target.Prop2);
            WithProp3(target.Prop3);
            WithProp4(target.Prop4);
        }
        public int Prop1 => prop1;

        public string Prop2 => prop2;

        public int? Prop3 => prop3;

        public string Prop4 => prop4;

        public TSelf WithProp1(int value)
        {
            prop1 = value;
            return this;
        }

        public TSelf WithProp2(string value)
        {
            prop2 = value;
            return this;
        }

        public TSelf WithProp3(int? value)
        {
            prop3 = value;
            return this;
        }

        public TSelf WithProp4(string value)
        {
            prop4 = value;
            return this;
        }

        public TI Build()
        {
            return (TI)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), this)!;
        }

        public void Update(TI target)
        {
            var methodInfo = dic.GetOrAdd(typeof(TI), getUpdateMethodInfo);
            methodInfo.Invoke(target, new object[] { this });
        }

        private static MethodInfo getUpdateMethodInfo(Type optionType)
        {
            var types = getInheritanceHierarchy(typeof(TI));
            var methods = typeof(TI).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(mi => mi.Name == "Update");
            return types.Join(
                methods, t => t.Name,
                mi => mi.DeclaringType.Name,
                (t, mi) => mi)
                .First();

        }

        private static IEnumerable<Type> getInheritanceHierarchy(Type type)
        {
            for (var current = type; current != null; current = current.BaseType)
            {
                yield return current;
            }
        }

   public static implicit operator TSelf(TargetManager<TSelf, TI, T> builder)
        {
            return (TSelf)builder;
        }
```

Plus this class inherited from that abstract class:

```
  public class TargetManager : TargetManager<ITargetManager, ITarget, Target>,ITargetManager
        {
            public TargetManager(ITarget? target = null) : base(target)
            {
    
            }
        }
```

and this class has used that interface:

```
public abstract class TestTargetManager<TSelf, TBuilder, TI,T>
    where TSelf : TestTargetManager<TSelf, TBuilder, TI,T>
    where TBuilder : ITargetManager<TBuilder, TI>
    where TI : class, ITarget
    where T:TI

{
private TBuilder targetManager;

public int Prop1 => targetManager.Prop1;

public string Prop2 => targetManager.Prop2;

public int? Prop3 => targetManager.Prop3;

public string Prop4 => targetManager.Prop4;

public TestTargetManager()
{
    targetManager = CreateBuilder();
}

protected abstract TBuilder CreateBuilder();

public TSelf WithSomeProperties()
{
    targetManager.WithProp1(1).WithProp2("test1");

    return this;
}
public TSelf WithSomeOtherProperties()
{
    targetManager.WithProp3(2).WithProp4("test2");

    return this;
}

public TI Build()
{
    return (TI)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), this)!;
}

public static implicit operator TSelf(TestTargetManager<TSelf, TBuilder, TI,T> manager)
{
    return (TSelf)manager;
}

}
```

this class implement that class:

```
public class TestTargetManager : TestTargetManager<TestTargetManager, ITargetManager, ITarget,Target>
{
    protected override ITargetManager CreateBuilder()
    {
        return new TargetManager();
    }
}
```

and i used it in test class:

```
  [Fact]
        public void Test6()
        {
            var sutBuilder = new TestTargetManager()
                .WithSomeProperties()
                .WithSomeOtherProperties()
                .Build();

            Assert.Equal(1, sutBuilder.Prop1);
            Assert.Equal("test1", sutBuilder.Prop2);
            Assert.Equal(2, sutBuilder.Prop3);
            Assert.Equal("test2", sutBuilder.Prop4);
        }
```

but in the TargetManager abstract class with has an implicit cast does not work so i had to change that cast to the below cast:

```
public static implicit operator TSelf(TargetManager<TSelf, TI, T> builder)
        {
            return (TSelf)(ITargetManager<TSelf, TI>)builder;
        }
```

why i have to first covert it to the interface and then cast it to TSelf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the constraint of `TSelf` is

```
where TSelf : ITargetManager<TSelf, TI>
```

That means `TSelf` is not just `ITargetManager<TSelf, TI>`, but any implementions of `ITargetManager<TSelf, TI>`, for instance `TSelf` could be:

```
class Foo : ITargetManager<Foo, ITarget>
```

So the type conversion from `TargetManager<TSelf, TI, T>` to `TSelf` is not a simple reference conversion, it's a user-defined conversion which is itself, that's why you got a `StackOverflowException`.

When you change it to

```
return (TSelf)(ITargetManager<TSelf, TI>)builder;
```

There are two steps, the first one is from `TargetManager<TSelf, TI, T>` to `ITargetManager<TSelf, TI>`, it's a simple reference conversion because `TargetManager<>` implements `ITargetManager<>`. The second one is from `ITargetManager<TSelf, TI>` to `TSelf` which is called [explicit interface conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1035-explicit-reference-conversions).